# Complex solutions of $(x+1)^{10}+(x-1)^{10}=0$

Tags: analysis, complex-numbers

Solve $$(x+1)^{10}+(x-1)^{10}=0$$

What method is available to solve this equation?

Comment: Your tag is pre-calculus. You are aware that there are no real solutions and, technically, there are ten complex solutions. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes. What tag should I put ?

Comment: Something with complex numbers. This is not a standard pre calculus question.(I am not saying it is a bad question!) When you expand, realize that the odd powered terms cancel, and so you are only left with even powers. Setting $x^2=t$ results in a fifth degree polynomial with all terms present and no real solutions. Quite a challenge...

Comment: Expanding is a very bad idea. Better to think about how $x+1$ and $x-1$ must be related, given that the 10th power of the one is the negative of the tenth power of the other.

Comment: To complete the only answer below which actually starts to try to address the question, using the change of variable $$z=\frac{x+1}{x-1}$$ (since $x=1$ is not a solution), the equation to be solved is equivalent to $$z^{10}=-1=e^{i\pi}$$ whose solutions are $$z=e^{i\theta}$$ for every $\theta$ such that $$10\theta=\pi\bmod{2\pi}$$ that is, $$\theta\in\{\pi/10,3\pi/10,\pi/2,7\pi/10,9\pi/10,11\pi/10,13\pi/10,3\pi/2,17\pi/10,19\pi/10\}$$ Now, **to fully solve the exercise, one must come back to $x$**, which ...

Comment: ... is done using $$x=\frac{z+1}{z-1}=\frac{e^{i\theta}+1}{e^{i\theta}-1}=-i\cot(\theta/2)$$ hence the solutions are $$x\in\{\pm i\cot(\pi/20),\pm i\cot(3\pi/20),\pm i,\pm i\cot(7\pi/20),\pm i\cot(9\pi/20)\}$$

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by Gerry Myerson's comment , put $\frac{x+1}{x-1}=z$ for some complex $z,x\neq1$ Then, $x=\frac{z+1}{z-1}$. Now your equation reduces to $z^{10}=-1$, which is easily solvable by using Euler's/De-Moivre's Theorem as $z=e^{i\phi},\phi=\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{10},k\in\mathbb{Z^+\cup 0}:k<10$ from which $x$ can be calculated

Comment: Yes, that's smart. +1

Answer (score -1):

For $x\in \mathbb{R}$ $(x+1)^{10}+(x-1)^{10}=0$ don't have any solution. This is true by the argument Dr.Sonnhard Graubner.

So let's rewrite question, $$(z+1)^{10}+(z-1)^{10}=0\text{ for }z\in \mathbb{C}.$$

Then suppose if $(z-1)^{10}=0,$then $\implies z=1$ , but $(1+1)^{10}\not=0$ hence $(z-1)^{10}\not=0$.
\begin{gather}
\Rightarrow\frac {(z+1)^{10}}{(z-1)^{10}}+1=0 \\ \frac{z+1}{z-1}=\sqrt[10]{-1}
\\
\end{gather}
Hence $z=\frac{1+\sqrt[10]{(-1)}}{\sqrt[10]{(-1)} -1}$.